# Trying to create json object in Java but getting nested array? How to do it in a better way?

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, jackson

I am trying to get this output:

```
{
   "columnNames":[
      "fruit"
   ],
   "values":[
      [
         "Apple is green"
      ]
   ],
   "time":"2017-12-11T00:00:00Z"
}
```

But I am ending up with the following...

```
{
   "columnNames":[
      "fruit"
   ],
   "values":[
      [
         {
            "stringValue":"Apple is green",
            "intValue":0,
            "booleanValue":false
         }
      ]
   ],
   "time":null
}
```

> Here is my code (so far) and I would appreciate if you could tell me where I am going wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    columnNames.add("fruit");
    List<List<ResponseValues>> responseValues = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ResponseValues> values = Collections.singletonList(new ResponseValues("Apple is green"));
    responseValues.add(values);

    String expectedResult = createAJson(columnNames, responseValues);
    System.out.println(expectedResult);
}


public static String createAJson(List<String> columnNames, List<List<ResponseValues>> values) {
    String jsonBlock = "";
    repBuilder repBuilder = new repBuilder();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    repBuilder.setColumnNames(columnNames);
    repBuilder.setValues(values);

    try {
        jsonBlock = mapper.writeValueAsString(repBuilder);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonBlock;
}
```

> And some boiler plate code to create the response value section:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"columnNames",
"values",
"time"
})

public class RepBuilder {

    public List<String> columnNames;
    public List<List<ResponseValues>> values;
    private String time;

    @JsonProperty("columnNames")
    public List<String> getColumnNames() {
        return columnNames;
    }

    @JsonProperty("columnNames")
    public void setColumnNames(List<String> columnNames) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
    }

    @JsonProperty("values")
    public List<List<ResponseValues>> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    @JsonProperty("values")
    public void setValues(List<List<ResponseValues>> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @JsonProperty("time")
    public String gettime() {
        return time;
    }

    @JsonProperty("time")
    public void settime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

> And response values: This was done this way so I can set STRING or INTEGER or BOOLEAN and add to list?

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ResponseValues {

    private String stringValue;
    private int intValue;
    private boolean booleanValue;

    public ResponseValues(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public ResponseValues(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public ResponseValues(boolean booleanValue) {
        this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public void setStringValue(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    public void setIntValue(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public boolean getBooleanValue() {
        return booleanValue;
    }

    public void setBooleanValue(boolean booleanValue) {
        this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what I am missing? I also tried to use `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` but that doesn't work for me, any other ideas? **I would appreciate if you use my code in context of your answer (as im still learning java)**

Comment: You're never setting the time, so it's null. And you have a List<List<ResponseValues>> although you want a List<List<String>>. So you end up in the JSON as an array containing an array of objects instead of an array containing an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom a serializer for `ResponseValues`, for example:

```
public class ResponseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ResponseValues>{ 

    @Override
    public void serialize(ResponseValues responseValues, JsonGenerator gen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        gen.writeString(responseValues.getStringValue());
    }

}
```

and use it with annotation:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ResponseSerializer.class)
public class ResponseValues
```

### Update

If you need check them in order, you can do it like this:

```
@Override
public void serialize(ResponseValues responseValues, JsonGenerator gen,
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

    String stringValue = responseValues.getStringValue();
    if (stringValue != null) {
        gen.writeString(responseValues.getStringValue());
        return; // if string value is valid, write it and return
    }

    int intValue = responseValues.getIntValue();
    // let's suppose 0 is not a valid status
    if (intValue != 0) { 
        gen.writeNumber(intValue);
        return;
        // also you can use gen.writeString(String.valueOf(intValue)); if you need a String
    }

    boolean booleanValue = responseValues.getBooleanValue();
    gen.writeBoolean(booleanValue);

}
```

Comment: Did exactly this and get no values at all in them for columnNames and values?`{
   "columnNames":[

   ],
   "values":[

   ],
   "time":null
}`

Comment: @Saffik Really? I get `{"columnNames":["fruit"],"values":[["Apple is green"]],"time":null}`.

Comment: Yeah I get null, also would this work if I choose to not `getStringValue` but for `getIntValue` or `getBooleanValue`

Comment: @Saffik The code you post does not compile. It seems you should replace `values.add(values);` with `responseValues.add(values);` and make `createAJson` static. So it compiles and output `{"columnNames":["fruit"],"values":[["Apple is green"]],"time":null}`.

Comment: OK - with your suggestions it work. One more thing though.. If I do in main method the following: `List<ResponseValues> values = Collections.singletonList(new ResponseValues(4));` - This won't work? as ResponseSerializer only writes getStringValue? Any idea how to make it work for the getIntValue and getBooleanValue?

Comment: @Saffik Then you need do more in the `serialize` method of `ResponseSerializer `. For example, you can check first if `getStringValue` returns valid  result. If it does, use the String it returns. If it returns empty result, then check `getBooleanValue` or `getIntValue`.

Comment: Right... I tried putting an if statement to see if responseValues is string by using `instanceof String` then do something... if integer, do something, if boolean do something etc... but I don't think it worked! Can you give me an example please? :) - I get error inconvertable types, cannot cast ResponseValues to Integer

Comment: Oooo i see what you done. I shall remember this for next time ;) - thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
private int intValue;
private boolean booleanValue;
```

These(int,boolean) are primitives, so these are by default initialised with default values of 0 and false respectively. You can use

```
private Integer intValue;
private Boolean booleanValue;
```

and configure writer to ignore null values.
Also,I don't see where you are setting "time". Since it is of type String, it has null as default in your output.

Last coming to Suggestion since you are learning java,

- Start your class names with a capital letter.Change `repBuilder -> RepBuilder`
- I loved your Collections.singletonList() and your efforts are evident in your question. Keep growing!

Comment: I shall do, thanks for your recommendation. One thing though, how do i tell writer to ignore null values? do i use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`?

Comment: Yes exactly! Also,  And you have a List<List<ResponseValues>> although you want a List<List<String>> as mentioned by @JB Nizet in comments

Comment: Ahan. With the above to ignore null values, I still get `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException)`

Comment: Please post the complete exception which you are getting

Comment: OK - having a look now. Trying a few things... :)